# A condition to all variable in r

Tags: r, dataframe, conditional-statements, sapply, tapply

I want to make a table consisting of 0 and 1.
If a variable is larger than 0, it will be 1 otherwise 0.
As the dataset has over 1,000 columns, I should use the 'sapply?' function on this question.

how do I make the code?

Comment: Please see my answer and next time please provide a reproducible example of your dataset.

Answer (score 1):

We can specify the condition and replace the value for a data frame. No "apply" family function is needed.

```
# Create an example data frame
dt <- data.frame(A = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4),
                 B = c(4, 6, 8, 0, 7),
                 C = c(0, 0, 5, 5, 2))
# View dt
dt
#   A B C
# 1 0 4 0
# 2 1 6 0
# 3 2 8 5
# 4 3 0 5
# 5 4 7 2

# Replace values larger than 0 to be 1
dt[dt > 0] <- 1

# View dt again
dt
#   A B C
# 1 0 1 0
# 2 1 1 0
# 3 1 1 1
# 4 1 0 1
# 5 1 1 1
```